# How to read a txt file, store the list of that txt file in a variable list using a for loop and then print the variable list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, text-files

How to read a txt file, store the list of that txt file in a variable list using a for loop and then print the variable list?

This is a code to output a variable list. I am looking to save the
lines from a txt file called scores into a variable list. Then print
the variable list

```
 Scores = open("scores","r")
 ** I use this line to read the scores function **
  
Scores = []
** This is the variable list I am going to store the txt file in by 
  using the for loop to go through each line in 'scores'**
  
  for line in Scores:
** takes the first line of the txtfile scores **
      
      line = line.strip()
 ** removes whitespace of that line.**
      
      Scores.append(line)
 ** Then adds that line to the variable list Scores ** 
     
     Scores.close()
 ** stops once the list hasn't gone through each line in the txt 
file ands stored in the variable list.**

print(Scores)
** suppose to print the value of scores in a list** 

output=[]
** however my output is []**

** Desired output example = Scores [ 'A 1' , 'B 3' ... etc] **
 



if this helps with context, the textfile scores is:
A 1
B 3
C 5
D 3
E 1
F 5
G 4
H 3 
I 1
J 10
K 8
L 3
M 5
N 3
O 2
P 5
Q 20
R 3
S 3
T 2
U 1
V 10
W 12
X 16
Y 8
Z 20
```

Comment: I'm not really great at python but in half a day I had a csv reader up that reads numpy lists and convert them to 'Pandas' DataFrames and do some stats on them. Look especially for examples on csv reading into Pandas. Seems to be everything you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read .txt File -> list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976716/python-read-txt-file-list)

Comment: Yes this answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your code to this.

```
with open("scores.txt","r") as file:
    scores = [line.strip().replace('\n','') for line in file.readlines()]
print(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a function to loop through and add each line:

```
def read_txt(file):
    scores = []
    with open(file, 'r') as input_file:
        for line in input_file.readlines():
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
            scores.append(line)
    return scores
```

**Explanation:**

```
scores = []
```

This creates a new list called `scores`.

```
with open(file, 'r') as input_file:
```

The above line of code is used to open the desired file, and assigning it to the variable `input_file`.

```
for line in input_file.readlines():
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    scores.append(line)
```

This loops through each line of code, removing any line breaks `\n` and appends it to the list `scores`.
run the function using the following line of code:

```
print(read_txt(What file you want to use goes here))
```

Comment: their is no output, the complier skips over the code

Comment: You have to run the function by `print(read_txt(what file you want to use goes here))`

Comment: Thnak you for your help